# finding values in specific name in object

Tags: javascript, filter

How to get a specific value from object, here is my sample object and pseudo code to get my expected result:

```
items = [
    {code: "1", fruits: "APPLE", color: "red"},
    {code: "2", fruits: "BANANA", color: "dummy"},
    {code: "3", fruits: "BANANA", color: "anotherDummy"},
    {code: "4", fruits: "ORANGE", color: "orange"}
]


items.find("BANANA")
```

should I need to loop it or there is a function that can easily find the values.
    Expected result:

```
2,"BANANA","yellow"
3,"BANANA","anotherDummy"
```

Comment: items = [{code: "1", fruits: "APPLE", color: "red"},
{code: "2", fruits: "BANANA", color: "dummy"},
{code: "3", fruits: "BANANA", color: "anotherDummy"},
{code: "4", fruits: "ORANGE", color: "orange"}];

var items2= items.filter(function(hero){ return hero.fruits=="BANANA"; });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `filter` method

```
let filteredArray = items.filter(item => item.fruits ==='BANANA');
console.log(filteredArray);
```

***UPDATE***

for more dynamic filters you can create a list of strings you want to find lets say:

```
let fruitsToFilter = ['BANANA', 'APPLE',...]
```

and then you can use the filter method like this to achieve the dynamic filtering

```
let filteredArray = items.filter(item => fruitsToFilter.includes(item.fruits));
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: Is it possbile if I search BANANA and APPLE at the same time on this line?

Comment: yes, you can just use `||` operator and add multiple conditions

Comment: yeah I tried and working as expected, but in my case I need a dynamic sometimes I need to find 2,3 or more.

Answer (score 2):

You can you `filter` of Array

```js
const items = [
  {code: "1", fruits: "APPLE", color: "red"},
  {code: "2", fruits: "BANANA", color: "dummy"},
  {code: "3", fruits: "BANANA", color: "anotherDummy"},
  {code: "4", fruits: "ORANGE", color: "orange"}
];

const keyword = 'BANANA';

const filter = items.filter(item => (item.code === keyword || item.fruits === keyword ||item.color === keyword));

console.log(filter);
```

Also for multiple filter/search

```js
const items = [
  {code: "1", fruits: "APPLE", color: "red"},
  {code: "2", fruits: "BANANA", color: "dummy"},
  {code: "3", fruits: "BANANA", color: "anotherDummy"},
  {code: "4", fruits: "ORANGE", color: "orange"}
];

const keyword = ['APPLE', 'BANANA'];

const filter = items.filter(item => (
  keyword.includes(item.code)
  || keyword.includes(item.fruits)
  || keyword.includes(item.color)
));

console.log(filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this could help -

- this code will return the array with found items
- this will compare the value given across all properties / keys of each item.
- additionally its better to create custom (created findCustom() function) rather override the built-in find() method.

```js
   var items = [{code: "1", fruits: "APPLE", color: "red"},
    {code: "2", fruits: "BANANA", color: "dummy"},
    {code: "3", fruits: "BANANA", color: "anotherDummy"},
    {code: "4", fruits: "ORANGE", color: "orange"}]
    
    items.findCustom = (value) =>{
     let results = [];
     items.find((item) => {
     var listKeys = Object.keys(item);
     listKeys.forEach((keyName) => {
      if(item[keyName] == value) 
       results.push(item);
      
    })
    })
    return results;
    }
    console.log(items.findCustom("BANANA"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = [{
    code: "1",
    fruits: "APPLE",
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    code: "2",
    fruits: "BANANA",
    color: "dummy"
  },
  {
    code: "3",
    fruits: "BANANA",
    color: "anotherDummy"
  },
  {
    code: "4",
    fruits: "ORANGE",
    color: "orange"
  }
]


const idx = items.filter((item, i) => item.fruits == "BANANA" ? item : '');
console.log(idx);
```

Comment: you can find anything from this thing color,code etc only need to replace item with item.key.

Comment: `arr.filter((item, i) => item.fruits == "BANANA" ? item : '')` returns the same result as `arr.map((item, i) => item.fruits == "BANANA" ? item : '').filter(String)`. So why are you using **map**

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution. Hope this helps!

```js
const items = [{code: "1", fruits: "APPLE", color: "red"},
{code: "2", fruits: "BANANA", color: "dummy"},
{code: "3", fruits: "BANANA", color: "anotherDummy"},
{code: "4", fruits: "ORANGE", color: "orange"}];

items.filter((item, index) => {
  return item.fruits == "BANANA"
}).map((o,i) => {
 console.log(Object.values(o));
 /* To get keys from the object you can use Oject.keys method */
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
can be used to filter elements

```js
var items = [{
    code: "1",
    fruits: "APPLE",
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    code: "2",
    fruits: "BANANA",
    color: "dummy"
  },
  {
    code: "3",
    fruits: "BANANA",
    color: "anotherDummy"
  },
  {
    code: "4",
    fruits: "ORANGE",
    color: "orange"
  }
];

var items2 = items.filter(function(hero) {
  return hero.fruits == "BANANA";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items = [
  {code: "1", fruits: "APPLE", color: "red"},
  {code: "2", fruits: "BANANA", color: "dummy"},
  {code: "3", fruits: "BANANA", color: "anotherDummy"},
  {code: "4", fruits: "ORANGE", color: "orange"}
]

let results = items.filter(o => o.fruits ==='BANANA')

results.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(`${item.code}, ${item.fruits}, ${item.color}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to do multiple searches on array, better create a `Map` first.

```js
items = [{ code: "1", fruits: "APPLE", color: "red" },
{ code: "2", fruits: "BANANA", color: "dummy" },
{ code: "3", fruits: "BANANA", color: "anotherDummy" },
{ code: "4", fruits: "ORANGE", color: "orange" }]

let itemsMap = items.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.set(curr.fruits, [curr, ...acc.get(curr.fruits) || []]), new Map());
console.log(itemsMap.get("BANANA"))
console.log(itemsMap.get("ORANGE"))

let multi = ['BANANA', 'ORANGE'].map(e => itemsMap.get(e)).flat();
console.log(multi)
```